# get the copy of database from mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Let's say I remote from my workbrench to the database which is on server now for some reason I need to have copy of the database on my another computer as a local database. How can  I do that?

Comment: Googling "Mysql copy database" should give you all you need?

Comment: I know but since database is not on my local computer I am in doubt if export/import works for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export it to a single file (`whatever.sql`), then import it by running the script on your local computer.

There's a "Data Export" link on the left side if you connect to the remote server using MySQL Workbench. Click on that and go through the export process. Then connect to your local server, click on "Data Import/Restore", and choose the file you just saved.

Comment: Even if I remotely connect to server does this work? (because database is not on my local computer and it is on server )

Comment: Yes; I do backups this way all the time.

Answer (score 1):

First export data from database, then import database or specific table import in local server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

To dump all MySQL databases on the system, use the --all-databases shortcut:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > [backupfile.sql]
```

Source :[How to Copy (Backup) a MySQL Database](http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/backup.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a dump and restore you can try the MySQL Workbench migration module which allows to migrate from MySQL to MySQL (useful for instance to upgrade from a previous version or to copy a schema, as in your case).

- MySQL Workbench migration (general description, video tutorial, white paper): http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/
- The MySQL Workbench migration wizard: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard.html